# choosing BPEL engine

Tags: bpel

I need to choose an open source BPEL engine for my work. I'm new to BPEL and I've never worked with any BPEL engine. Which engine would you recommend me that is  easy to configure and use for a begginer? Brief explanation but I really have to experience at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used Oracle's BPEL engine about two years ago. It was both a nightmare to configure, and fairly half-baked in terms support. Even their example code didn't work properly. Things may have changed since then.

Comment: things haven't changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

We use [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/) at work, and it works fine. The project support we have via mailing lists is enough for us.